# Can't show the local board on the clients side

Tags: java, multithreading, game-development, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

`enter code here`I'm developing a multiplayer snake game in Java, and for this, I require three classes: Server, Client, and RemoteBoard. The RemoteBoard class represents the game state, and it contains the information that needs to be sent to the client. However, I am encountering difficulties when the client receives this information and needs to update its own board.

There is a LocalBoard that represents the local game. I use it to create the RemoteBoard and provide it with the cells and obstacles from the local board. Subsequently, the server sends an object of type RemoteBoard, and the client receives it to update its own board.

*Server*

```
public Server(LocalBoard localBoard) {
            // TODO
            this.board = new RemoteBoard(localBoard);
}
private void processConnection() {
            try {
                do {
                    // Write object
                    out.writeObject(board);

                    System.out.println("Server sent a update");

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(board.REMOTE_REFRESH_INTERVAL);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }
                    
                } while (!board.isFinished());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

*Client*

```
private void processConnection() {
        try {
            board = new RemoteBoard();
            SnakeGui gui = new SnakeGui(board,600,0);
            gui.init();
            do{
                board = (RemoteBoard) in.readObject();
                board.setChanged();
            }while(!board.isFinished());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

*RemoteBoard*

```
public RemoteBoard(LocalBoard localBoard) {
        this.obstacles = localBoard.getObstacles();
        this.cells = localBoard.getCells();
        setChanged();
}
```

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.